# 2D Array Question Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

If I have a 2D array `arr[rows][columns]`, how could I use `arr.length` to find size for rows and columns individually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
arr.length
```

will be the number of rows

```
arr[x].length
```

will be the number of columns in row `x`.

Answer (score 6):

You can find the number of rows as:

```
arr.length
```

In Java all the rows need not have same number of elements. You can find the number of elements in the row `i` as:

```
arr[i].length
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Rows - arr.length
Columns -arr[rowNumber].length //Each row can have different number of elements
```